# Stateless with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, stateless-state-machine

Is it possible to use Stateless with Visual Studio 2015 without using .NET Core?

https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless

When loading the project, I get a number of errors with the sample projects:

> ...\Code\stateless-dev\src\Stateless\Stateless.csproj : error  : The default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format, please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old 1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.  ...\Code\stateless-dev\src\Stateless\Stateless.csproj

Adding the source files manually to the project also result in errors: 
[image]
Any pointers? Thanks.

Comment: It says it can **Stateless runs on .NET 4.0+ and practically all modern .NET platforms by targeting .NET Standard 1.0**  [REF](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless)

Comment: and the code errors are due to C# 7.0 throw expressions. If you want to use them in VS 2015 you need to install [Microsoft.Net.Compilers](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Compilers). It should build but VS will still show the red squiggly on that line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They only support **building** it in [VS 2017](https://github.com/dotnet-state-machine/stateless#building):

> Stateless runs on .NET 4.0+ and practically all modern .NET platforms
>   by targeting .NET Standard 1.0. Visual Studio 2017 is required to
>   build the solution.

You can grab the built library from [nuget - stateless](https://www.nuget.org/packages/stateless).